# Having an issue getting unique colors from image

Tags: python

I am trying to get the unique colors from an a simple digitized image (tiff file) with a few RGB colors. the code below works for a couple of the standard images that came with the code example but no when I recreate another image with the exact same colors. The this code snipped identifies the RGB colors in the image so that I can then use those same colors and attach specific properties to those colors for further analyses.

the error I'm receiving is "cannot reshape array of size 22138110 into shape (7379370,4)"

I wonder if I'm making a basic error and would appreciate any help!

```
s = mpimg.imread(r'C:\Users\ADC\Desktop\NewImage.tif')
s2 = np.reshape(s,(s.shape[0]*s.shape[1],4))
b = np.ascontiguousarray(s2).view(np.dtype((np.void, s2.dtype.itemsize * s2.shape[1])))
dummy, idx = np.unique(b, return_index=True)
print (s2[idx])
```

Comment: My first guess would be that the image you are trying to use is in RGB while the example was in RGBA. Try changing the third reshape parameter from 4 to 3.

Comment: @rauberdaniel you nailed it - didn't realize that RGB vs. RGBA was a thing but that completely fixed it, thanks!!